# Amend width of external poll once its submitted

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've created a simple polldaddy poll. I'm amending the width & hiding some elements of the poll once its loaded using jQuery as below :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $(".pds-pd-link").hide();
    $(".a2a_dd.pds-share").hide();
    $(".pds-box").width(220);
  });
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="http://static.polldaddy.com/p/5968383.js"></script>
<noscript><a href="http://polldaddy.com/poll/5968383/">This is a test question ?</a></noscript>
```

The problem is once I vote the width of the poll reverts back to its original width. Is it possible to retain the with at 220 ? I realise amending the width this way is a bit of a hack and its possible to do full customisations once a license is purchased. I just want to amend the width for now.

Here is a fiddle for the poll : http://jsfiddle.net/Wx5mM/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use CSS instead, with `!important`: http://jsfiddle.net/Wx5mM/1/.

```
.pds-box {
    width: 200px !important;
}​
```